# What return type should I expect for SELECT DISTINCT for multiple columns in room?

Tags: android, kotlin, select, distinct, android-room

I use room for my app and want to query a table for each unique combination of recordingId and markerId:

```
@Entity(tablename = "table")
data class Table(
  val recordingId: Int, 
  val markerId: Int,
...)
```

TableDao:

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT markerId, recordingId FROM table GROUP BY recordingId")
    fun getRecordingWithMarkTyps(): LiveData<List<Pair<Int,Int>>>
```

However, I am unsure how I'm supposed to map the expected output to the Query results.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Query) suggests, you can directly convert the result into an object, with the correct implementation.

In your case, you could declare it like these:

```kotlin
data class Table(
  val recordingId: Int, 
  val markerId: Int,
...)

@Query("SELECT DISTINCT markerId, recordingId FROM table GROUP BY recordingId")
abstract fun getRecordingWithMarkTyps(): List<Table>
```